# nodejs mysql insert null datetime field

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysqljs

*using mysql-ssh*

How to insert DateTime field's value to null in MySQL through nodejs?

**Tried following:**

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO idea_steps (field1, field2) VALUES(?, ?)', ['value1', null])
connection.query('INSERT INTO idea_steps (field1, field2) VALUES(?, ?)', ['value1', ''])
connection.query('INSERT INTO idea_steps (field1, field2) VALUES(?, ?)', ['value1', 'null'])
connection.query('INSERT INTO idea_steps (field1, field2) VALUES(?, ?)', ['value1', undefined])
```

***Table Structure:***

```
field1 String
field2 DateTime Default null
```

***Error:***

*for ''*

```
Incorrect datetime value: \'\' for column \'field2\' at row 730
```

**for undefined**

```
Unknown column \'NaN\' in \'field list\'
```

**for 'null'**

```
Incorrect datetime value: \'null\' for column \'field2\' at row 730'
```

**for null**

```
Unknown column \'NaN\' in \'field list\'
```

Can anyone help me to insert DateTime field to null? I can't skip the `field2` field. Let me know if it is even possible, if not I'll have to figure out something else.

Comment: Hi, can you tell the structure of table you are using (column names).

Comment: What is the error that is getting generated when you try any of these ways?

Comment: `''` and `'null'` should definitively **not** insert a null value.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Just tried because some answers on other questions stated that... but no success

Comment: Is that the actual code, with a literal `null`, or you're reading the value from a variable you believe to be null?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález both actually.. I tried with variable and also tried concatenating inside the string but both fail to update

Comment: Shouldn't the query be a string? For example: `connection.query("INSERT INTO idea_steps (field1, field2) VALUES ?", ['value1', null])`

Comment: @DhruvShah Query is string.. I replaced variable with a query that's why I forget to add quotes... but still, if the query was not string ..I won't get the above listed errors.. :/

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `connection.query` seems faulty over here.

It should be:

```
const sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO idea_steps (field1, field2) VALUES ?";
const values =  [ ['field1', 'NULL'] ];

con.query(sqlQuery, [values], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });
```

Comment: I have just added a callback function to `conn.query` and provided the`sqlQuery` parameter as a `string`, based on the documentation available for mysql-.ssh `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-ssh`

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near` Getting this... Not working....